# Android: How to make an AutoCompleteTextView SingleLine?

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/product"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="product"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

this is my code for AutoCompleteTextView.

The problem is I want to type in some text and then click `Next` on the soft-keyboard. `Next` is appearing on the soft-keyboard but its not taking cursor to the next `EditText`. In the same screen rest all EditText have the same code and they work fine. Is AutoCompleteTextView any different from normal `EditText` in such case??

Comment: sorry, the Next button appears but when i click it doesnt take the cursor to the next EditText, same problem with all the AutoCompleteTextViews i am using, for EditText it works fine

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in AutoCompleteTextView in xml .

Comment: fine it works. But what is wrong with android:singleLine="true". which worked fine for EditText?

Comment: we need `inputType` along with `imeOptions` as @EvanB mentioned

Answer (score 16):

Setting `android:inputType="text"` on the `AutoCompleteTextView` element in the layout XML worked for me; limits input to one line and the `Next` soft key is present. Pressing the `Next` soft key didn't actually advance input to the next `AutoCompleteTextView` in my Activity until I also added `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`.

I couldn't find anything in the reference site to support this, but Content Assist in Eclipse seems to indicate `android:singleLine` is deprecated (at least in this context):

> Constrains the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of 
>    letting it wrap onto multiple lines, and advances focus instead of 
>    inserting a newline when you press the enter key. * Deprecated: 
>    This attribute is deprecated. Use "maxLines" instead to change the 
>    layout of a static text, and use the "textMultiLine" flag in the 
>    inputType attribute instead for editable text views (if both 
>    singleLine and inputType are supplied, the inputType flags will 
>    override the value of singleLine). [boolean]"

Comment: Using `android:inputType="text"` and `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` works for me, but when I click the **Next** button, I'm not taken to the next view. Is there anything I need to add to the next view?

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue with My AutoCompleteTextView. It was working fine before android:singleLine="true" deprecated. But once i set android:maxLines="1",it is not worked until i put android:inputType="text"

```
AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    />
```

by placing android:inputType="text" on the AutoCompleteTextView it worked for me.

may help you guys :)

Answer (score 5):

Just add this two below lines. It will be fine.

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:inputType="text"
```

or,

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:inputType="text"
```